# Why is my Wordpress Timber component breaking the page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, timber

I'm currently building a website with a number of components in Timber, however I have one specific component that breaks the page entirely on mobile and I'm unsure why.

I can only assume it's something to do with either the WP loop or the ajax call. I've never had this issue in the past when running WP loops, however I'm fairly new to Timber itself so I'm wondering whether there is something specific that I'm missing that's Timber-related.

```
//functions.php
<?php
namespace Flynt\Components\Portfolio;
use Timber\Timber;

const POST_TYPE = 'portfolio';

add_filter('Flynt/addComponentData?name=Portfolio', function ($data) {
    $postType = POST_TYPE;

    $data['path'] = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Components/Portfolio';

    $data['items'] = Timber::get_posts([
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => $postType,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
    ]);

    $data['go_to_market_options'] = Timber::get_terms([
      'taxonomy' => 'Go To Market',
      'hide_empty' => true,
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'asc'
    ]);

    $data['funding_stage_options'] = Timber::get_terms([
      'taxonomy' => 'Funding Stage',
      'hide_empty' => true,
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'asc'
    ]);

    $data['industry_options'] = Timber::get_terms([
      'taxonomy' => 'Industry',
      'hide_empty' => true,
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'asc'
    ]);

    return $data;
});

function filter_portfolio() {
  $context = Timber::get_context();

  $context['orderby'] =  $_POST['orderby'];

  $args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => $context['orderby'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'cache_results'  => false,
  );

  if($context['orderby'] == 'name'):
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
  endif;

  $context['items'] = Timber::get_posts($args);

  Timber::render( 'Partials/portfolio-loop.twig', $context );

  die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_portfolio', 'Flynt\Components\Portfolio\filter_portfolio');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_portfolio', 'Flynt\Components\Portfolio\filter_portfolio');


//scripts.js
...
const getPortfolioResults = () => {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
          action: "filter_portfolio",
          orderby: orderby,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $loadingIcon.hide();
          if (data.length) {
            $(data).insertAfter($(".portfolio-grid div#insert"));
          }
        },
        error: function () {
          $loadingIcon.hide();
          $(".no-results").fadeIn();
        },
      });
    };
...


// portfolio-loop.twig
{% for item in items %}
  {% include "Partials/portfolio-item.twig" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you explain what “breaks the page” means?

Comment: Hi Chris, sure - it seems to work absolutely fine on Desktop, however on Mobile whenever I pinch and zoom or filter the portfolio, the page reloads and then says 'a problem repeatedly occurred'. I've also noticed on another page using Ajax with a 'load more posts' button, the same issue occurs.